# How to emit single values from array using rxswift?

Tags: rx-swift

How to emit single values from array using rxswift? Let say I have an array contains user details of a company, and I want to emit each users one by one using rxswift.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
Observable.from(array)
```

This converts an array to an observable sequence.

More info about the from operator: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html